# Can a thread executing in it's critical section be preempted in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

If it can be ,then what if the thread that preempts the current running thread tries to acquire lock on the same object ? Those threads will forever be in a deadlock,right?

Comment: I'm talking about single processor systems in which only one thread can be scheduled at any given time.

Comment: No. a thread that tries to acquire the lock on an object and can't because it's held by another thread is put in BLOCKED state until the lock is released, letting other threads execute.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it:

- Thread A acquires lock X
- Thread A is "suspended"
- Thread B wants to lock on X, too
- Thread B is blocked

What makes you think that "Thread B is blocked" results in thread A **not** getting executed at some point?

So yes, given the above scenario, A and B are currently not progressing. But nothing prevents A from being resumed to continue its work, and to release X at some point.

Beyond that, the usual disclaimers: in 2018, there are almost no more single processor systems (that run java). And "pre-emption" is a pretty fuzzy concept, and the actual "threading behavior" of JVMs very much depends on the JVM type and the underlying OS.

Regarding the priority situation: any reasonable implementation will pick the "next" thread to give cycles to from the set of threads that **can** actually progress. It doesn't matter if B has higher priority: it is blocked. If A can progress, and B can't then *at some point* A will progress and should release the lock.

Comment: But acquiring the lock does not have to be the first instruction thread B executes,right ? sorry, I completely forgot to mention that I'm talking about priority based preemption. So as soon as thread B goes into ready state ,it should get scheduled.

Comment: Does it matter? B is running, and at some point it wants the lock. I really don't see why it would matter what else B is doing. For the priority stuff, see my edit.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point completely . I have one more question, if a higher priority that has preempted a lower priority thread gets suspended,then  what will be the state of the thread it has preempted?

Comment: According to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lifecycle-and-states-of-a-thread-in-java/ ... there is only the running state. But as the javadoc, the underlying details depend on the OS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Thread.State.html